# TFS 2013 code review Send and Finish

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

We have a Code Review policy in our development team that restrict developers from submitting new code unless you have a Code Review with 5 "Looks Good". The option Send & Finish of the Code Review has 3 options:

1. Looks Good
2. With Comments
3. Needs Work

If we mistakenly select "With Comments" instead of "Looks Good" TFS finish and send your review as finished With Comments without actually having any comments.

My question is, can I prevent TFS from finishing and sending "With Comments" if there are not comments on the review.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with any standard options, nor any plugins I've seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this with the current implementation of Code Review in Visual Studio for TFVC.